Can I deploy an application created by Visual Studio 2022 Community edition on domain PCs without licensing Issues?
I am developing an application using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Community edition  on my home computer, which is not connected to a domain.
If I compile and extract the .exe (C# Userform) file for this application, will I be able to install and run it on work computers that are connected to a domain, or will I encounter licensing or permission issues?
I am concerned about potential problems related to any licensing restrictions associated with using Visual Studio Community Edition. Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.

There is NO need to install Visual Studio Community Edition to distribute applications built with it. You should learn how to distribute C# applications in their various forms - including making an installer, handling click-once or a similar upgrade check, whether or not to embed the runtime (or demand it is separately installed).
Even if you are not allowed to distribute it - the application is not tied to the Community Edition in any technical form.
